# I installed RetroPie on my Ubuntu machine... Want some advice

Tags: boot

I want to run RetroPie on my machine from the start. In other words, I don't want to have it turn on and show Ubuntu and have to go through all of the steps to get to RetroPie. Any chance anyone here has a workaround to this so that I can boot directly to RetroPie?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Are you asking how to run an application on login?

Answer (score 1):

To have RetroPie Run at Startup try the following. 
** NOTE ** this is for Ubuntu Desktop v18.04.3

1.) Open Ubuntu Software.

2.) Click the Magnifying Glass in the top right corner to open a Search Filed.

3.) Type "Tweaks"

4.) Search for and Locate GNOME Tweaks

5.) Click Install

6.) Click Launch

7.) In the Left Menu click on "Startup Applications"

8.) On the Right side of the screen click the + at the top of the screen to add an application.

9.) Scroll down to find "rpie" and click on it, click add.

10.) Close the GNOME Tweaks and reboot to have Emulation Station start up in without hitting the Ubuntu Desktop!

Enjoy!!!